# Cannot install cluster autoscaler manually in an AKS cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, aks

I want to install Cluster Autoscaler for an AKS cluster **manually** (not enable cluster autoscale) but it doesn't work.
I tried many ways: using helm chart, using yaml files, but no one works.
I referred to some examples here:
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/examples/cluster-autoscaler-vmss.yaml
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/examples/cluster-autoscaler-aks.yaml
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/azure/examples/cluster-autoscaler-autodiscover.yaml

I checked logs of cluster autoscaler pod, it has following messages:

> Failed to scale up: Could not compute total resources: No node info for: agentpool

Is there any solution for this?